# drawImage() does not draw image

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get a .jpg image to draw on the screen using the drawImage() method, but It will not draw. Here is the code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Image image = new ImageIcon("tictactoeimg.jpg").getImage();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}
```

The .jpg file is within the src folder with the class. How can I fix this so it will draw the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method
2. Don't do I/O in a painting method. Painting methods are for painting.
3. Override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the component to return the size of the component otherwise the size is (0, 0) and there is nothing to paint.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

However, the real question is why are you trying to use drawImage. You can just use a `JLabel` with an `Icon`. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Icons` which contains a working example.

Comment: agree with not doing I/O in a painting method, but if the I/O is done elsewhere and the image is checked to be ready, why couldn't one do custom painting with the paint method?  `paintComponent` seems like a leap away from the original intent of the question.  If you are extending a [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html), for example, you need to override `paint`.

Comment: @Atreys, Canvas is AWT and yes you would override paint(). Swing does painting differently and `paintComponent()` is the proper method to override. Read the tutorial.